# Saving integer value for using in multiple procedures

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

After successful creation of custom procedure, I managed to integrate it in my case. Problem is: I need an integer publicly saved for more procedures, it is supposed to add health points if number is randomly rolled. Code doesn´t show any errors, but what I want isn´t working, I also tried moving the last part(begin) in the front, but that causes errors. Any suggestions? I tried using OnCreate to set the "hp" at start, but no success.

Code here:

```
var hp:integer;
{ TForm1 }
procedure TForm1.health;
begin
  Label6.Caption:= inttostr(hp);
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Play = Chooses action (Rolls a Dice)'
  + sLineBreak + 'Say = Write down a message and say it in the log'
  + sLineBreak + 'HP = Shows your current health points'
  + sLineBreak + 'ATK = Shows your current attack points '
  + sLineBreak + 'DEF = Shows your current defend points '
  + sLineBreak + ' '
  + sLineBreak + '    Actual game version: 0.1'
  + sLineBreak + '_Created by xxxxxxxxx');
end;
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var v:string;
begin
v:=Edit1.Text;
Log.Lines.Add('Player says: ' +v);
end;
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var p:integer;
begin
  randomize;
  p:=random(5)+1;
  case p of
  1: ;
  2: heal;
  3: Log.Lines.Add('Nothing happend');
  4: ;
  5: ;
  end;
end;
procedure TForm1.heal;
begin
     hp:=+10;
     Log.Lines.Add('HP+10');
end;
begin
OnCreate
hp:=100;
Log.Lines.Add('Start: 100HP, 10ATK, 0DEF');
end.
```

Comment: The 5 last lines in your code seems strange. It looks like something is missing. Please check. You should not use global variable but instead us a variable inside the form.  The are named - usually - with the prefix "F".

Comment: Define "isn't working"

Comment: One more comment: you should also pay attention to code indentation so that it is more readable. Use at least one empty line between procedures.

Comment: You can't learn a language this way. Find and read good book.

Comment: Judging by your qs today, you urgently need to read a book on Delphi's language, Object Pascal.  An excellent book by Marco Cantu of Embarcadero is available as a free download: https://lp.embarcadero.com/Object-Pascal-Handbook-2021?utm_source=Eloqua&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Article-210201-MulticontentDelphiShowcase

Comment: What do you think `:=+10` means?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `hp:=+10;` does not do what you think it does.  It sets the value of `hp` to *exactly* `10`, it does not *increment* the value of `hp` by 10.  For that, you would need to use either:

`hp := hp + 10;`
or
`Inc(hp, 10);`

Also, the `hp` variable should *ideally* be a data member of the Form, not a global variable.

And, you should be using the Form's `OnCreate` event to perform initializations.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Label6: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    hp: integer;
    procedure ShowHealth;
    procedure Heal;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
  hp := 100;
  ShowHealth;
  Log.Lines.Add('Start: 100HP, 10ATK, 0DEF');
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowHealth;
begin
  Label6.Caption := IntToStr(hp);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Play = Chooses action (Rolls a Dice)' + sLineBreak +
              'Say = Write down a message and say it in the log' + sLineBreak +
              'HP = Shows your current health points' + sLineBreak +
              'ATK = Shows your current attack points ' + sLineBreak +
              'DEF = Shows your current defend points ' + sLineBreak +
              sLineBreak +
              '    Actual game version: 0.1' + sLineBreak +
              '_Created by xxxxxxxxx');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  v: string;
begin
  v := Edit1.Text;
  Log.Lines.Add('Player says: ' + v);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: integer;
begin
  p := random(5) + 1;
  case p of
    1: ;
    2: Heal;
    3: Log.Lines.Add('Nothing happened');
    4: ;
    5: ;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Heal;
begin
  hp := hp + 10; // or Inc(hp, 10);
  ShowHealth;
  Log.Lines.Add('HP+10');
end;
```